# Can I substitute basic GSON for basic ObjectIn/OutputStreams?

Tags: java, serialization, gson

If I just drop in `.toJson` and `.fromJson` instead of using `.writeObject` and `.readObject`, will I get identical results?
Additionally, what's the GSON equivalent of the `readObject` and `writeObject` methods that you can put in classes to be serialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson doesn't support inheritance or circular references sufficiently to be a drop-in replacement for Java Serialization.

For **inheritance**, use [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) to encode class names in JSON values.

For **circular references**, you can use [GraphAdapterBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/graph/GraphAdapterBuilder.java) to encode values by reference rather than by value.

Neither of these files are included in the Gson distribution. You'll need to copy and paste them into your app if you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Gson AFAIK does not have readObject & writeObject (according to it's [API](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html))

As for the second part of the question: GSON works like [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer): you can implement a serializer/deserializer like this:

```
private class DateTimeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<DateTime> {
    public JsonElement serialize(DateTime src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
    }
}
```

and then register them with `gson.registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, DateTimeSerializer());`